# make node look at the camera as it moves?

Tags: scenekit

So I have a node in the scene. The node is a text node. I want the text node to appear like it always points to the camera as I pan around. I am referring to the camera we get when we use `allowsCameraControl = true`. I tried to set a look at constraint to the current Point of view of the scene on the text node. However when I move around the scene using the default controls the text does not "look at" the camera but it turns around like any other node in the scene.

What am I doing wrong?

The constraint I used is this:

```
let lookAt = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: pov) // pov is the camera 
textNode.constraints = [lookAt]
```

Ok, I found the problem. The node was not getting initialized correctly. I was using this code:

```
let textNode:SCNNode? = self.scnKitView.scene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("textNode", recursively: false)
```

To make it work I set the `recursively` flag to `true` instead of `false`.

I thought that by providing the name of the node SceneKit would just find it without having to set that flag to true.

Comment: Quick question: how do you move the camera? Do you use the default controls or custom ones?

Comment: Default controls. I am just setting the allowsCameraControl to true and then simply setting the constraint in the renderer delegate where I first I get a reference to the current pointOfView.

Comment: Could you post the complete code?

Comment: @Moustach see edit. I had to set the recursively to true...